# Automorphism of $\Bbb{C}$ that takes a countable dense set to another

Tags: complex-analysis

I want to prove or disprove the following statement:

### *If $X$ and $Y$ are countable dense subsets of $\Bbb{C}$, then there is an $F\in$ Aut($\Bbb{C}$) such that $F(X) = Y$.*

I'll disprove it by giving a counterexample:

Let $X = \{(p+iq) \in \Bbb{C} : p,q \in \Bbb{Q} \}$, $Y = X \cup \{\sqrt2 + i\sqrt2\}$.

Let $F\in$ Aut($\Bbb{C}$) satisfy the above condition, i.e., $F(X) = Y$.

If $F\in$ Aut($\Bbb{C}$), then $F(z) = az+b$ for some $a,b \in \Bbb{C}$ and $a\neq 0$.

Let $x_1,x_2 \in X$ be such that $f(x_1),f(x_2) \in X$. Then we have:
$$ax_1 + b = y_1 \\ ax_2+b = y_2$$

These equation will uniquely determine $a$ and $b$ (if not, then we choose some other pairs). This will give us $a,b \in X$. Hence there is not preimage of $(\sqrt2 + i\sqrt2)$

### Is this correct?

Comment: In such a case, I prefer the word [biholomorphism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Biholomorphism) than automorphism

Comment: The word automorphism is usually used for a bijection $ f $ that preserves sums and products $(\;f(a+b)=f(a)+f(b)$ and $f(ab)=f(a)f(b) \;) .$ However, your logic is correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's correct.  Though of course you have a cleaner statement there: An affine mapping $az + b$ is determined by its action on two points.  Therefore, you can at most specify a two point set $X$ and a two point set $Y$.

A more general statement is that an automorphism of the Riemann sphere, a linear fractional map, is determined by 3 points.  Above, a map that takes $\mathbb C$ to $\mathbb C$, is actually already specifying that $\infty$ goies to $\infty$, and so you have only 2 points left to play with.